# favorite song function in music app android studio

Tags: android

I am writing favorite function for music app, I would like change image when I click the love image. But It only change image from deselected to selected when I click again, it cannot be deselected
this is my code:

```
public void Favorite() {
    isLike = listSong.get(currentIndex).isLike();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (isLike) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "remove the favorite song", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ivLove.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_love);
                isLike = false;
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "add the favorite song ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ivLove.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_love_selected);
                isLike = true;
             }
         }
}
```

Please help me fix issue, thanks so much!

Comment: you're changing the value of `isLike` in if-else but not setting its value in `listSong`. that might be a reason behind this issue.

Comment: @ ganjaam Thank you for your suggestion! It really help me